# GNOME doesn't work on Debian Jessie after installing fglrx

Tags: debian, gnome, gdm, ati, fglrx

I'm using 64bit Debian Jessie and followed these instruction to install fglrx for Radeon HD 7000 series: https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary

However GNOME doesn't work after it. I installed different desktop environments and it worked. With GNOME, GDM doesn't start, and launching GNOME with `startx` crashes. What is the problem?

Comment: Check your /var/log/Xorg.0.log to see if you can get more information about your problem.

Comment: Try my post:

>[How to install AMD Catalyst 15.7 (fglrx 15.20.1046) on Debian 8 (Jessie)?][1]


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222000/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-15-7-fglrx-15-20-1046-on-debian-8-jessie?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

I have installed debian wheezy with a few upgrades required to work with steam imported from jessie.  While doing that upgrade make sure you don't upgrade the main xorg files.  I've been enjoying some nice 3d rendering in games.  I'll also add that the fglrx I'm using is directly from amd, and not the debian version.

Comment: You might want to consider expanding this answer to include extra information (e.g., commands or package versions relevant to the upgrades you mention).

Answer (score 0):

Jessie has been released as stabile now, and the [answer to this question](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/i386/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#gnome-fglrx) is included in official upgrade documentation: missing support of the EGL interface.