# How to install AMD Catalyst 15.7 (fglrx 15.20.1046) on Debian 8 (Jessie)?

Tags: linux, gnome, fglrx, amd-graphics, dkms

A while ago I downloaded Debian 8 and I tried to install Catalyst 15.7, but when restarting the computer, I get a black screen on my laptop.

I read that Catalyst has some compatibility issues with GNOME. If any of you know how to fix this error, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

** Update 2015/09/21 **

- New links for mutter packages

---

Some time ago I try to install Catalyst 15.7 in most Linux distributions with GNOME and after several attempts I managed to install it.

In this answer I will show you how to install Catalyst 15.7 on Debian 8 regardless of the desktop environment that you use.

Just to clarify, I have used this procedure in the following desktop environments:

- KDE
- GNOME
- Cinnamon
- XFCE

Before we begin, we need to install some dependencies, so we will open a terminal and execute the following command:

> `sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make dkms fakeroot`

After installing dependencies we can proceed downloading Catalyst from the official website of AMD:

> [AMD Catalyst 15.7](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86)

After downloading Catalyst, we must unzip. In the folder where you unzip Catalyst we will open a terminal and run the following commands:

First, we will give execution permissions.

> `chmod +x amd-driver-installer-15.20.1046-x86.x86_64.run`

Then we proceed to install the driver.

> `sudo ./amd-driver-installer-15.20.1046-x86.x86_64.run --install`

Once the driver is installed, it will ask if you want to restart the computer. Select "no".

Now we need to create a configuration file for the X server, so execute the following command:

> `sudo aticonfig --initial`

Note: If you need to use different options with aticonfig command, please read the help of it, running in a terminal the following command:

> `aticonfig --help`

**GNOME users only.**

Unfortunately Catalyst has some compatibility issues with GNOME, so, to correct, we must run in a terminal the following commands:

> `su`
>
> `echo "export COGL_DRIVER=gl" >> /etc/environment`
>
> `echo "export COGL_OVERRIDE_GL_VERSION=1.4" >> /etc/environment`
>
> `echo "export COGL_RENDERER=GLX" >> /etc/environment`
>
> `echo "export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2" >> /etc/environment`

The previous commands helps mutter to detect the version of OpenGL, with this, the issue with GDM is solved.

Now we need help mutter to detect the version of OpenGL that our GNOME session can load properly. To do this, run in a terminal the following commands without root permissions:

> `touch ~/.xsession`
>
> `echo "export COGL_DRIVER=gl" > ~/.xsession`
>
> `echo "export COGL_OVERRIDE_GL_VERSION=1.4" >> ~/.xsession`
>
> `echo "export COGL_RENDERER=GLX" >> ~/.xsession`
>
> `echo "export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2" >> ~/.xsession`
>
> `echo "gnome-session" >> ~/.xsession`

**GNOME laptop users only.**

In laptops, gnome-shell crash, reason for the crash is an X error asserting arguments to
XRRChangeOutputProperty called from
mutter-3.14.4/src/backends/x11/meta-monitor-manager-xrandr.c:output_set_presentation_xrandr

To correct this error, we must recompile "mutter" with a patch source. For users of the amd64 architecture can save the job, downloading the following files, which compiled and packed it myself.

> [gir1.2-mutter-3.0_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/#!vkFGzIrD!-NfAhixHLWIMUtTY_z_nzHXwbJNsBfFZJtkjBwrVaMg)
>
> [libmutter-dev_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/#!Sl0hzYyL!HzMCpdPC8K9_W8IUOg4Vn2YwXOaYulv-Ua3pj3LEZ4E)
>
> [libmutter0e_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/#!ak1g3ZoC!tR2tzS0iXLyrNFxo690J-MBqQCK5CbQH5OA8afHPz7w)
>
> [mutter_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/#!b1cg0RBQ!39MHA7XbAhoLgG7maEMCREGpjNN1zie8d9-C60HxNgo)
>
> [mutter-common_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_all.deb](https://mega.nz/#!WwM0BajI!525gLH37ttvo3aGtFYd6hRK_QueXlUeDng6XKpvapUA)
>
> [mutter-dbg_3.14.4-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/#!Xk0kULoY!zggnLLVzIVun1dfs-Pd4TJSJPK9H-LCgeeC4tA14bDo)

For users of the i386 architecture, soon I'll upload the packages compiled and packaged, so stay tuned to this guide.

To install the packages need to open a terminal in the folder where you downloaded the packages and run the following command:

> `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

If we have problems with some dependencies when installing packages, it is only necessary to run the following command:

> `sudo apt-get -f install`

And with that we're done. Now we just have to restart our computer to enjoy Catalyst 15.7.

Comment: Should this work for ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: You can try it.

Comment: I did everything exactly as you said, @R4v3nPr0, but when the system attempted to start the login screen, it crashed and showed a message saying that something went wrong and a button logout. After clicking on this button, nothing happened. So, I had to boot using the recovery mode in order to remove the fglrx drivers and then be able to login again.