# Install AMD RADEON 5450 HD on debian 8 with KDE environment

Tags: debian, kde, ati, radeon, amd-graphics

I just did a fresh installation of Debian 8 (jessie) on my HP dv6 64bit laptop with a Radeon 5450 HD graphics card. I wanted to install the proprietary ATI driver, but at the installation I just got a tty1 console and KDE desktop is no longer available. I followed these [instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222000/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-15-7-fglrx-15-20-1046-on-debian-8-jessie) but they don't seem to work for me. I also tried to install the [ati free driver](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo) from Debian sources but it doesn't work either!

Any help?

Comment: You might need to install the appropriate firmware to make the driver work correctly. See...https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Radeon

Comment: Please upload your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (to pastebin or similar). And as munircontractor wrote it is important the correct version of ATI driver.