# Max brightness too dim Debian + Gnome + Fglrx

Tags: debian, brightness, amd-graphics, fglrx, asus

I'm running:

- Debian Jessie
- Gnome3
- fglrx drivers
- Asus Laptop : `VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R6 Graphics]`

The max screen brightness is too dim.

I have tried manually adjusting it with xrandr and xbacklight but nothing happens. 
I recently install fglrx drivers to fix the issue of the gnome login screen becoming frozen after hibernating. This issue remains.

```
echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

The above also does nothing

Followed this guide for installation:
[How to install AMD Catalyst 15.7 (fglrx 15.20.1046) on Debian 8 (Jessie)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222000/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-15-7-fglrx-15-20-1046-on-debian-8-jessie)